# space metris disjoint

Tags: metric-spaces

Let F  be a closed subset of a metric space M  and p∈M∖F . Show that there are two disjoint open sets G  and H  in M  such that p∈G  and H⊆F .

I solved well but I think is not the way ...
We take a point y belonging to F. We have inf {d (p, y)}> 0 after p belongs to (M-F). F y belongs to a subset that is closed because its complement M is then opened out all the points are interior points F and then we can say that inf {d (p, y) / p belongs to (M-F)} and y belonging to F > 0.
Then we can consider a good B (p, r) ta r = inf {d (p, y) / y belongs to F} / 3. Also, a ball B (y, r).
We have that G is an open ball in M and H is also open ball in M, and we have the union of the two is an empty set.